# Using Matrix in BitmapData.draw()

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I need to draw a BitmapData into an other one and the result should be a tile formed by 4x the source at 1/4 the size.
Right now I am using 4 calls to BitmapData.draw() with a matrix to scale down the source and a clip rectangle to draw in each corner, but I'm wondering if the same result could be achieved with a single draw call.

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: Not with bitmapdata.draw(), but you can do it if you want to use graphics.beginbitmapfill()+graphics.drawrect(). That allows you to tile if you want to go that route.

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks! Looks like graphics is only related to Sprite or Shape, so I can't draw directly in my BitmapData, right?

Comment: correct. not directly to bitmapdata.